# Stop application while doing some operations

Tags: java, search, task

I created an application that search a word in each file contained in a directory.
I wanted to implement a way to stop searching.
I created a method that calls other diffent methods according to each file type it find in the directory.
I have worked in one single class and I created a `JButton` that request stop searching:

```
 private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {                                         
            System.out.println("Requesting stop");
    }
```

I need a way to stop the method that search into the directory, suppose my method is `search(directory);`.

I tried to `search(directory);` in this way:

```
private Thread a;
a = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
     @Override
     public void run() {
       search(directory);
     }
        } 
  );
```

and then while searching I click the `jButton` to stop search:

```
 private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {             
            System.out.println("Requesting stop");                            
            a.stop(); 
    }
```

It works but I have been reading many posts about this and it's not a good way to stop a thread.
So any alternative? Could you give an example?

I have also tried this:

```
java.util.TimerTask timerTask;
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThread = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
timerTask = new  java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            search(directory);
        }
    };
scheduledThread.schedule(timerTask, 3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and then in `jButtonActionPerformed`:

```
 private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {                                         
       System.out.println("Requesting stop");
       scheduledThread.shutdownNow();
    }
```

It works too, but in this case I'm not able to start a new search when I try to do it. I need to close and reopen application.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

- The code that does the searching should be in its own class.
- Your GUI controller (for instance, the ActionListener) will create an object of this class.
- When your GUI wishes for the Search class to do searching, it should call a method of the class, perhaps `beginSearch()` and do so on a background thread.
- The Search class should have a method for stopping an active search, say `stopSearch()` that a GUI controller can call.
- This method will probably set a boolean field, a *flag*, of the Search object, say called `continueSearching` or something similar, one that its search method intermittently checks during its searches. If the boolean is set to false, then the search should stop.

Also note that you are correct. Calling `stop()` on a thread is not only not recommended, but it is down-right dangerous. Please have a look at what the [Thread API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) has to say on the subject:

> Deprecated. This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior. Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it is to stop running. If the target thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used to interrupt the wait.

Also please have a look at this link: [Why is Thread.stop deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

---

**Edit**
You state:

> the problem is that my application code is long and it will be hard to edit it like your way,...

The longer your class is, the *more* important it becomes to try to break it up into separate logical units. Else you'll end up with a debugging and enhancing nightmare.

> i'm not an expert in programming and i'm still studying for that, that's why I wanted to know whether there was a way according to my situation.

The more you practice refactoring, the better you'll get at it and the easier it becomes. A good time to start is now.

Comment: ok thanks, but what if I can't make a own class for the searching method?

Comment: @Frank: I don't understand -- what's stopping you from making your own class for this? I suppose you could have the boolean flag as a field of your GUI, but that has a bad code smell to it, a [god-class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_class) type of smell.

Comment: the problem is that my application code is long and it will be hard to edit it like your way, i'm not an expert in programming and i'm still studying for that, that's why I wanted to know whether there was a way according to my situation, but that's ok thanks.